# Is SQLite 2 database header format different from that of SQLite 3?

Tags: sqlite, file-format

I determine whether the file is SQLite database by reading the first 16 bytes of the file (as described in https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html). If I've read `SQLite format 3`, then it's an SQLite database.

I don't have a sample SQLite 2 database so I don't know what header it has, and I couldn't find about it in docs. Anyone knows what the header is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it doesn't explicitly say that the header has changed, I believe that the first 16 bytes would be different, at least in that the **3** (15th byte x'33') would likely not be **3**, which is sufficient for SQLite3 to consider the file incompatible.

What you could do is to obtain a version via [History Of SQLite Releases](https://www.sqlite.org/chronology.html) and read the **readme** at [SQLite Source Repository](https://www.sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/README.md). Compile and perform testing to suit.

You nay also find [File Format Changes in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/formatchng.html) and additionally [SQLite Version 3 Overview](https://www.sqlite.org/version3.html) of some interest.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. actually they don't have downloads for 2.x.x versions. and i looked up the "SQLite format" string in their website and found this file: https://www.sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/magic.txt, but te first check-in was in 2014, and with the string "SQLite format 3"

Answer (score 1):

SQLite 2 databases start with

```
** This file contains an SQLite 2.1 database **
```

I have only seen 2.1 databases, but probably 2.0 databases start with 2.0 instead of 2.1

Answer (score 1):

For SQLite 2 databases, these are the possible prefixes (as quoted C strings, without an implicit trailing `\0`), based on SQLite 2.0.0 ([GitHub mirror](https://github.com/sqlite/sqlite/blob/90ca975338e5d647cb63051aa3e443c28f0ae167/src/btree.c#L101-L103), [official repo](https://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/tarball/1df5386a/SQLite-1df5386a.tar.gz) and SQLite 2.8.0 ([GitHub mirror](https://github.com/sqlite/sqlite/blob/30710453cae779998fc9e64313e593fa0cc37e48/src/btree.c#L108-L110), [official repo](https://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/tarball/5db98b3f/SQLite-5db98b3f.tar.gz), [on SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openqnx/files/SQLite/SQLite%202.8%20_%20qnx6.2.0/sqlite-2.8.0-qnx6.2.0.tar.gz/download)) source code, constant `zMagicHeader` in source file `src/btree.c`:

```c
"** This file contains an SQLite 2.0 database **\x00\xda\xe3\x75\x28"
"** This file contains an SQLite 2.0 database **\x00\x28\x75\xe3\xda"
"** This file contains an SQLite 2.1 database **\x00\xda\xe3\x75\x28"
"** This file contains an SQLite 2.1 database **\x00\x28\x75\xe3\xda"
```

For SQLite 3 databases, these are the possible prefixes (as quoted C strings, without an implicit trailing `\0`), based on the [official file format documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#the_database_header) and SQLite 3.0.0 ([GitHub mirror](https://github.com/sqlite/sqlite/blob/8107be2c7e64a2a9679b229966d945b28d53a97a/src/btree.c#L240-L243), [official repo](https://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/tarball/8b409aaa/SQLite-8b409aaa.tar.gz)) source code, constant `zMagicHeader` in source file `src/btree.c`:

```c
"SQLite format 3\x00\x00\x01"
"SQLite format 3\x00\x02\x00"
"SQLite format 3\x00\x04\x00"
"SQLite format 3\x00\x08\x00"
"SQLite format 3\x00\x10\x00"
"SQLite format 3\x00\x20\x00"
"SQLite format 3\x00\x40\x00"
"SQLite format 3\x00\x80\x00"
```

Relevant version numbers were taken from the [official file format changes document](https://www.sqlite.org/formatchng.html).